# [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, react-native

Estoy con react native y android studio intentando hacer el siguiente fetch(post):
Version de android 12

(import FormData from 'form-data';)

```
    formData.append("photo", img);
    formData.append('name', 'hola');
    fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8080/user/register", {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
             Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          },
        body: formData
    }).then(response => {
        console.log("image uploaded")
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Pero se muestra el siguiente error: [TypeError: Network request failed]

Estuve buscando por mi parte y me dicen que debo agregar:

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` al archivo `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`
Y tambien agregue el archivo `android\app\src\main\res\xml\network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">_my_clients_ip</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Pero nada funciona.

Comment: pregunta, el form data es un objeto ? y lo probaste en postman a ver si lo que esta fallando es la carga que le estas anidando al formData. probalo en postman la misma peticion post pero al body agregale cualquier cosa pero en formato correcto. capas estas mandando un body de otro formato.

Comment: Si hago:  ` let formData = new FormData();`  y tambien lo probe en postman y anda perfecto.